# Linking a class's properties to other values?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, language-agnostic

When using a class to represent some data obtained externally, I often find the need to link the properties of that class to the properties of the data. I'm most familiar with Javascript, so when this comes up, the first thing I think of is to create an array containing the property name on one object and the property name on the external data.

For example, if the data was:

```
var jsonObj = {
    "aString": "this is a string value",
    "aNum": "44235",
    "aColor: "125,125,125"
}
```

I might create an array structure like:

```
var linker = [
    ["aString", "title", "string"],
    ["aNum", "userCount", "int"],
    ["aColor", "color", "color"]
]
```

to keep track of the source property name, what the property name will be on the new object, and what type the value is. I'm having a hard time thinking of a similar solution in a non-high-level language, like C#. Reflection comes to mind, but it doesn't seem like to correct place to use it.

**How can I relate a set of strings to a set of properties without doing the following?**:

```
obj.setTitle(data.getValue("aString"));
obj.setUserCount(data.getValue("aNum"));
obj.setColor(data.getValue("aColor"));
...
```

Comment: Automapper is usually used to achieve such object to object mapping.https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.                    Is that what you are looking for

Comment: @CodeIgnoto, This is way too basic to justify including any external code. I'm looking for a design pattern that solves this problem.

Comment: "a non-high-level language, like C#" - what languages you consider "high level"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I consider PHP, Python, Javascript, Groovy, Perl, and similar languages to be high level.

Comment: I see "high level"="dynamically typed". See if [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) works for you in C#...

Answer (score 0):

C# has System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer Class
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx

Or May you use Json.NET.
This is Json parser.
Thus, you can use Dynamic Type.

http://json.codeplex.com/

I'm not good at English.
I'm sorry if I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) / [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) will make C# look more friendlier to you

I.e. you can set/get any properties on `dynamic` object initialized with `ExpandoObject`

```
dynamic v = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
((IDictionary<String, Object>)v).Add("test", 3);
Console.Write(v.test);
```